# Deploying a web application for Selenium testing on AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, selenium, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, selenium-firefoxdriver

I have a web application that uses Selenium in backend to run few scripts when invoked by user. I want to deploy this web app on  AWS.

Here are my findings so far:

1. I can have a windows EC2 instance created and then I can install `tomcat`, `firefox` and all the necessary stuff. Then using `putty` or any other client, I can deploy my war and start tomcat.
2. I can directly make use of `Elastic Beanstalk` and deploy my war file there itself but then, there is no windows EC2 available for beanstalk and I don't know how to install firefox there and make my application work.

What is the best way to achieve this and what steps should I follow. I want to install a specific firefox version to be able to make it run with my selenium scripts.

Answer (score 1):

There are two separate things here:

- Deployment of web application on AWS cloud
- Run the selenium tests against your web application

According to me, you should first think of deploying a web application to AWS cloud. There are many ways by which you can get it deployed to AWS cloud with below services:

- Spin a new AWS EC2 instance, install all required software and deploy the web application.
- Use AWS elastic beanstalk service with either with tomcat or docker.
- Use AWS ECS if you prefer docker

According to me, second option will be quick for you with tomcat environment option. If you select tomcat environment, then your platform will be `Tomcat 8 Java 8 on 64bit Amazon Linux`.

Now, here comes the second part. You can have below options for your browser environments.

- Spin a new separate AWS EC2 instances with correct AMI and install your specific browsers on these instances.
- If you prefer SaaS, then you can take a look at [browserstack](https://www.browserstack.com/) or [SauceLabs](https://saucelabs.com/) for remote environment.

If you have CI(jenkins/travis/Circle CI), then make use of that infrastructure to luanch your tests with either option from the above.

Comment: `Spin a new separate AWS EC2 instances with correct AMI and install your specific browsers on these instances.` : This is when I deploy the application on EBS? How will this instance map with where my application is deployed?

Comment: This will be independent on AWS EB instances. This can be created later, once your web application is up and running. You will have to refer the web application url e.g. `https://{AWS_EBB_HOST}:{PORT}/{APP_CONTEXT}/{PATH_TO_WEB}` in your selenium code. Basically, you need to set the url in `driver.get(url);` api.

Comment: My use case if different. My web application takes in a webpage URL as a user input from UI, does some backend processing(invoking url with `driver.get()` and performing some data scraping) and returns the JSON response. Now, to implement this backend processing, I need to have browser installed.

Comment: Sorry, I thought that you are testing your web application using selenium script application. In that case just use one AWS EC2 instance with correct AMI and install all your necessary installable.